# Rails active record sort with a conditional. mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

i'm trying to sort a query by two conditionals.  First query is if the 'percentage' is above 75 and if it's not it will then sort by a 'grade'  The percentage belongs in a another table than the grade.  for example, the first query could look something like this but would only be for values above '75:

```
joins(:school_annual_data => :school_eligibility_data).order("GREATEST(school_annual_data.survey3_low_percent, school_eligibility_data.low_income_percent)")
```

Then the query would look like:

```
order('school_type ASC')
```

How can I combine them together?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to commas separate them in the same parenthesis.

```
.order(condition_1 ASC, condition_2 ASC)
```

So in your case:

```
.order("GREATEST(school_annual_data.survey3_low_percent, school_eligibility_data.low_income_percent), school_type ASC")
```

See more: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

Comment: Thanks, how does this check if the "percent" is a certain number?